# JQuery function doesnt work after an other does

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

this code is from a cart of a music store I have made. The problem is that I need to check if the quantity I choose in the cart is in available in the stock. It works but if the user changes the quantity in the input number, the button pagar(pay) doesnt work. If I reaload the page it works but I need to do it without reload. The code:

```
$("#pagar").click(function() {
  var tt_precio = $("#t_compra").text();
 //solo cojo el precio tt y le quito el €;

 var tt_precio = tt_precio.split(" ")[4];
 var tt_precio = tt_precio.slice(0, -1);
 var precios = [];

 var fecha = new Date();

 var date =
   fecha.getFullYear() +
  "/" +
  Number(fecha.getMonth() + 1) +
  "/" +
 fecha.getDate();

 $("[id*=precios]").each(function() {
 var p = $(this)
  .text()
  .slice(0, -1);
precios.push(p);
});
var cantidades = [];
$("[type = number]").each(function() {
cantidades.push(Number($(this).val()));
});
var referencias = [];
$("[id*=referencias]").each(function() {
referencias.push($(this).text());
});
var nombres = [];
$("[id*=nombres]").each(function() {
nombres.push($(this).text());
});

var datos = {
precios: JSON.stringify(precios),
cantidades: JSON.stringify(cantidades),
referencias: JSON.stringify(referencias),
nombres: JSON.stringify(nombres),
tt_precio: tt_precio,
fecha: date
};
$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: datos,
url: "compra.php",
success: function(vuelta) {
  alert(vuelta);
  window.location.href = "/AccesoDatos/index.php";
}
});
});

$("seguir")

//cambiar precios
$("input").change(function() {
var valor = $(this).val();
var id = $(this).attr("id");
//para eliminar el simbolo del €
var precio = $("#precios" + id)
.text()
.slice(0, -1);
var datos = {
cantidad: valor,
referencia: id,
precio: precio
};

$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: datos,
url: "modificarCantidades.php",
success: function(datos) {
  if (datos == -1) {
    $("#span" + id).html("No hay suficientes unidades");
  } else {
    if (datos == 0) {
      $("#fila" + id).remove();
      $("#t_compra").html("0€");
      $("#precio").html("0");
    } else {

      $("#span" + id).html("");
      var precio = $("#precios" + id)
        .text()
        .slice(0, -1);
      var cantidad = datos;
      var total = precio * cantidad;
      $("#total" + id).text(total + "€");
      //alert(total);
      var total_precio = 0;
      var total_Cantidad = 0;

      // coge todos los elementos que contienen en el id la palabra total y suma su valor
      $("[id*=total]").each(function() {
        var p = Number(
          $(this)
            .text()
            .slice(0, -1)
        );
        total_precio += p;
      });
      //coge los inputs number para sumarlos
      $("[type = number]").each(function() {
        var c = Number($(this).val());
        total_Cantidad += c;
      });

      //meto los valores nuevos en su sitio;   --> en ajax hay que modificar el array de sesiones.
      $("#unidades").html(total_Cantidad);
      $("#precio").html(total_precio);
      $("#t_productos").html(
        "<strong>Total productos:</strong>" + total_Cantidad + "UDS"
      );
      $("#t_compra").html(
        "<strong>Total de la compra:</strong>" + total_precio + "€"
      );
    }
  }
}
});
});
```

It work clicking a button the first one and changing some input type="number", the problem is that if I use the onChange function, then I need to pay the updated cart but it is not posible because the button pay function doesn't work, I dont know why, I've tested whit an alert() at the top of the function, just below the call and it works but doesnt happend from there.

Comment: There is a lot of code here.  It would be easier for people to help if you can edit it down to *only* the code needed to show the problem. Try to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've delete the last two fragments of code that seems not much useful, sorry for the long code but I cant find if the problem is in the php or in the jquery code.

Comment: Looking at your JS, clicking on `pagar` does an AJAX POST and then redirects to `/AccesoDatos/index.php` - is that the PHP file you've shown us? Still too much here for us to be able to work out what you are trying to do.  [I started a jsFiddle  with *much simplified* code](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/ejmfdrt2/), maybe you can take it and simplify further to create a working example which shows the problem.

Comment: No, the index.php is where the page redirects after the user clicks the pay button, but it is no relevant in this case. I have updated the question, and try to descrive better the problem, sorry.  Thanks for your help creatin the JsFiddle but its not posible to run the code there because I use a local database. Maybe it is, but i dont know how to make run my code there.

Comment: That's the point of the [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - we don't have your DB either, but for this problem it (probably) isn't relevant.  All you/we need are some numbers, like the random prices etc I added in the jsFiddle, so we can stick them into your HTML and get something like what you have on your page. The actual numbers are (probably) not important either.

Comment: Yes, they are relevant. What onChange makes is to search the product that has changed  in the DB, check if the stock is greather than the quatity I choose, and send using Ajax a response. If it is -1, then I show a message, if it is 0 I delete that product from the cart, and else I updated the quantities at html using jquery. I cant simulate the response if I dont make the ajax process. And the problem is that if I recived the ajax answer from this process, then I cant pay. I think the problem is that the data I'm trying to take has been updated using Js .

Comment: I've solved it, the problem was that the variable tt_precio was not set, when I click the button it does nothing because I dont update that value. Sorry for the ambiguous question and thank you so much for your help and for discover me https://jsfiddle.net, it will help me in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change the below function:**

`$("input").change(function() {`

For input field types change trigger function should not be used, try changing it with `keyup function` with 5 sec delay.
That might can help you out.

I have done something similar to this while you can use after doing some changes into it according to your need:-

```
//setup before functions
var typingTimer;                //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 2000;  //time in ms, 5 second for example
var $input = $('#user_name');

//on keyup, start the countdown
$input.on('keyup', function () {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
});

//on keydown, clear the countdown 
$input.on('keydown', function () {
     clearTimeout(typingTimer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it, the problem was that the variable tt_precio was not set, when I click the button it does nothing because I dont update that value